# Deducing the null space from column relations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
> a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3}
> \end{bmatrix}$ and $3a_{1}+2a_{2}+a_{3}=0$ where $a_{i}$ are matrix columns. Find the nullspace of $A$.

So, my initial thought was that the nullspace is the span of the vector $\begin{bmatrix}
3\\ 
2\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$, but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to be not sure, indeed, without any other information what we can say is that the nullspace of $A$ contains the span of $(3,2,1)$ but we can't determine it.

Comment: +1: For example, $A$ could be the $3\times3$ zero matrix.

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes that's really a simple but very effective example!